# Remove an apostrophe at the beginning or at the end of a word with regex

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I have a list of `String` that contains word. Some words have apostrophe at the beginning or/and at the end like this:

```
apple
'orange
banana'
joe's
```

I want to delete only the apostrophes at the beginning and at the end of the words like this:

```
apple
orange
banana
joe's
```

I have tried with the following regex but it doesn't work:

```
myString.replaceAll("((?<=^)'|'(?=$))", "");
```

It does not work in IntelliJ:
[image]

But it works with [`regex101.com`](https://regex101.com/):
[image]

**Why the regex dosen't works and how can I remove the beginning and ending apostrophes?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try `\B'\b|\b'\B` or `(?m)^'|'$`

Comment: Didn't `^'|'$` work? When replacing, the matched start end end themselves should be left alone, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Both work, you should add it as an answer. Raffel no it doesn't, tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand my mistake, I forgot to make the assignment…

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("(\B'\b)|(\b'\B)", "");
```

Thank you and sorry for this dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to remove single quotes at the start or end of the line, you need to enable multiline mode (e.g. you may do it with an inline modifier `(?m)`):

```
(?m)^'|'$
```

As `^` and `$` are anchors, zero-width assertions, you need no lookarounds to enclose these anchors with.

If you really plan to match `'` that are not enclosed with word chars, use a word boundary based solution:

```
\B'\b|\b'\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w4SUjO/1)

**Details**:

- `\B'\b`  - a `'` that is preceded with a non-word boundary (there can be start of string or a non-word char immediately before `'`) and followed with a word boundary (there must be a word char after `'`)
- `|` - or
- `\b'\B` - a `'` that is preceded with a word boundary and is followed with a non-word boundary.

In Java, do not forget to use double backslashes with `\b` and `\B`:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\B'\\b|\\b'\\B", "");
```